# tinyMCE 5 with getUIKIT uk-accordion (hide/show div)

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, getuikit

I am using tinyMCE 5, and getUIKIT 3. I put the editor inside a uk-accordion, which allows me to show/hide the div. All goes well the first time I show the div, the editor is there fully functioning. I hide the div, show again - sometimes the editor is there sometimes not. From then on, it is never there when I hide/show.
Here s a codepen with the problem: https://codepen.io/prtome/pen/gJLdKo?editors=1111

and my code (very simple):
HTML

```
<ul uk-accordion>
  <li  id="toto">
    <a class="uk-text-primary uk-accordion-title" href="#">Item toto</a>
    <div class="uk-accordion-content">
        <textarea id="basic-example"></textarea>

     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

AND JS code:

```
UIkit.util.on('#toto', 'shown', function (event) {
 tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor',false, 'basic-example');
  $('#basic-example').html("<p style=\"text-align: center;\"> blabla bla bla bla bla I can edit this </p>");
  tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#basic-example',
  height: 200,
  menubar: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor ',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
 });
});

UIkit.util.on('#toto', 'hidden', function (event) {
 tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "basic-example");      
})
```

I have no errors in the console. I cannot find what it is that I am doing wrong - but it is obvious something is not working as it should. If anybody could point where the problem is it will be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to how UIKIT handles showing and hiding things.  If it uses `display:none` to "hide" elements when not visible and changes the visibility when the items are to be shown - this will cause issues for TinyMCE because when the element has `display:none` it is no longer part of the DOM.  When you later show the contents of the accordion the `display:none` is changed to `display:block` and the elements are now part of the DOM.   Effectively each time you show/hide something you are likely creating and destroying DOM elements.

What you need to do is not `init()` TinyMCE until the `<textarea>` is shown via the action that "shows" the appropriate `<textarea>`.  When you hide that accordion you need to use the `remove()` API to disconnect TinyMCE ***before*** the accordion close happens (e.g. before the `<li>` reverts to `display:none` and the elements are removed from the DOM).

I don't know if you can force UIKIT to use `visibility:hidden` as opposed to `display:none` but that would eliminate all of this if that is possible.

Comment: Thank you. I was beginning to think the problem was with the uk-accordion. My understanding is that the shown event is fired after the area is shown . I replaced the hidden event by beforehide, and tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "basic-example");    by tinymce.remove('basic-example)
Now I have the editor correctly showing every time, but not in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does seem to be some incompatibilities between the uk-accordion and tinyMCE. Since I don't really want to init many times the editor, I think the best solution is to put the text area outside the accordion. In my actual case I have the editor as the last accordion so it is not a problem.
so my HTML is now:

```
<ul uk-accordion>
    <li id="toto" class="uk-open">
        <a class="uk-text-primary uk-accordion-title" href="#">Item toto</a>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content" >
          <p>blablabla</p>
        </div>  
    </li>
</ul>
<textarea id="basic-example" class="uk-hidden"></textarea>
```

and JS

```
 $('#basic-example').html("<p style=\"text-align: center;\"> blabla bla bla bla bla I can edit this </p>");

  tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#basic-example',
  height: 200,
  menubar: true,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor ',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
  ],
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on('init', function(e) {
            e.target.hide();
        });
    }
});
UIkit.util.on('#toto', 'shown', function (event) {
  $('#basic-example').removeClass("uk-hidden");
  tinymce.editors['basic-example'].show();
})
UIkit.util.on('#toto', 'hidden', function (event) {
tinymce.editors['basic-example'].hide();
  $('#basic-example').addClass("uk-hidden");
})
```

it perfectly works, this is the codepen
https://codepen.io/prtome/pen/VObZaK